# SmartDiagram overlapping text

Tags: smartdiagram

I am using SmartDiagram with an additional module in a figure environment. However the additional module is being drawn outside the bounds of the figure environment:

[image: Overlap example]

How do I get the figure so it does not overlap the text?

Here is the current code I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\begin{document}
Some lines of text: these should be above the diagram.
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \smartdiagramset{
     circular distance=36mm,
     text width=35mm,
     module minimum width=35mm,
     module minimum height=15mm,
     module shape=rectangle,
     arrow tip=to,
     uniform arrow color=true,
     arrow color=gray!50!black,
     border color=black,
     uniform color list=white for 6 items,
     additions={
       additional item offset=15mm,
       additional item text width=35mm,
       additional item height=15mm,
       additional item shape=rectangle,
       additional item border color=black,
       additional item shadow=drop shadow,
       additional arrow color=gray!50!black,
     }
    }
    \smartdiagramadd[circular diagram:clockwise]{
            {Second Box (2)}, 
            {Third Box (3)}, 
            {Fourth Box (4)}, 
            {Fifth Box (5)}, 
            {Sixth Box (6)}
        }{
            above of module1/{First Box (1)
        }
    }
    \smartdiagramconnect{-to}{additional-module1/module1}   
    \caption{Example diagram.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently, the “above of module” box is ignored by the bounding box computations.

Comment: @egreg This is expected. The additions are added in a picture which uses the `overlay` option. (Page 7 of the manual.) However, the solution suggested is misleading, at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `additions` are added in a separate `tikzpicture` environment which uses the options `remember picture, overlay`. Consequently, these items do not update the bounding box, as explained on page 7 of the manual. The suggestion there is to use a `minipage`. However, in this case, it seems just as easy to do without.

Rather than use the `h` specifier, I'd use a `center` environment and `\captionof`, if a caption is required. That is, if you really do not want the figure to float. If you do want it to float, if necessary, then simply use `figure` with `\centering` as in your original example.

Either way, you need to manually leave space for the additional module in the diagram. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram,capt-of}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\begin{document}
Some lines of text: these should be above the diagram.
\begin{center}
  \vskip 30mm\par
  \smartdiagramset{
    circular distance=36mm,
    text width=35mm,
    module minimum width=35mm,
    module minimum height=15mm,
    module shape=rectangle,
    arrow tip=to,
    uniform arrow color=true,
    arrow color=gray!50!black,
    border color=black,
    uniform color list=white for 6 items,
    additions={
      additional item offset=15mm,
      additional item text width=35mm,
      additional item height=15mm,
      additional item shape=rectangle,
      additional item border color=black,
      additional item shadow=drop shadow,
      additional arrow color=gray!50!black,
    }
  }
  \smartdiagramadd[circular diagram:clockwise]{
    {Second Box (2)},
    {Third Box (3)},
    {Fourth Box (4)},
    {Fifth Box (5)},
    {Sixth Box (6)}
  }{
    above of module1/{First Box (1)
    }
  }
  \smartdiagramconnect{-to}{additional-module1/module1}
  \captionof{figure}{Example diagram.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: skip to compensate]

Comment: Thank you, adding the \vskip 30mm\par was all it needed.

Comment: Yes. It is a bit of a pain, but it is pretty much inevitable given the way the `additions` get added. `overlay` is overlaid over whatever is there, text or not. So you have to make sure it overlays empty space.